# Find all unit vectors at an angle $\theta$ with $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find all unit vectors $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which make an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with the vectors $$\vec{a_1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}\ \text{ and }\ \vec{a_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
$\vec{x}$ is such a unit vector if and only if $$\vec{a_1} \cdot \vec{x} = \lvert\vec{a_1}\rvert \lvert\vec{x}\rvert \cos(\pi/3) = 1 \\ \vec{a_2} \cdot \vec{x} = \lvert\vec{a_2}\rvert \lvert\vec{x}\rvert \cos(\pi/3) = 1.$$
Then we can look for unit vectors which are solutions to the system $A\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Conveniently, $A$ is already in reduced echelon form and we can see that solutions of the system are given by the line $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + x_3\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ $x_3 \in \mathbb{R}.$
We want to find $x_3$ for which the above are unit vectors. This gives the equation
\begin{align*}
1 &= \lvert \vec{x} \rvert^2 \\
&= (1 + x_3)^2 + (1 - x_3)^2 + x_3^2 \\
&= 2 + 3x_3^2
\end{align*}
which has no real solutions.

**Edit:** The above identities should yield the system $$A\vec{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and we get the equation $$1 = 2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 3x_3^2 \implies x_3 = 0$$ so we have just the solution $\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Didn't you forget $|\vec a_1|$ and $|\vec a_2|$?

Comment: Just a quick observation $\|a_1\|=\|a_2\|=\sqrt{2}$, so $a_i \cdot x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Another possible approach is to realize that such an $x$ is the bisector of the angle between $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: Ah my mistake! How embarrassing.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your reply. I had a quick question, if that's alright -- if you remove the restriction that $\lvert \vec{x} \rvert = 1$, does this allow for more solutions? I think not, because scaling $\vec{x}$ should not change the angles.

Comment: As a follow-up, why can't I just consider any solution $\vec{x}$ of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + x_3 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and then just normalize it by dividing by $\lvert \vec{x} \rvert$?

Comment: But you are stuck if you do that, because the right-hand side of the equation must have a factor of $|x|$, and you end up with nonlinear equations!

Comment: So try one of your alleged solutions (say with $x_3=1$). What happens?

Comment: Coincidentally, this problem appears in two of the textbooks I've written. :P

Comment: I guess there are two ways to think about this: any solution $\vec{x}$ of the above system makes an angle $\theta$ with $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$ satisfying $\cos(\theta) =\frac{1}{2 \lvert x \rvert}$. So  any such $\vec{x}$ which is not a unit vector will have the wrong angle, and since normalizing it doesn’t change the angle it still won’t be correct.

Comment: Alternatively, since the set of solutions is not a subspace, normalizing may end up with a unit vector which is outside the solution set. Is this the right way to think about this?

Comment: Haha yes, I am working through your book multivariable mathematics. It’s been really enjoyable so far!

Comment: I think the clearest way to think about it is to build $|x|=1$ into the equations and then impose that condition at the end. ... In case you don't know about them, in my profile you'll find a link to 112 YouTube lectures from my course out of the book at UGA just before I retired.